# Flipping the positions of items in a UIStackView

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have a `UIStackView`, created in `Interface Builder` that contains two views. Now I'm trying to programatically change the order of these views (exchange their positions, so to speak).

Is there an easy fix for this that ***DOES NOT*** use Interface Builder to accomplish this?

Thanks :).

Comment: How about changing semantic to .forceRightToLeft. That's an easy and quick but not a good fix.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a layout with 2 `UIViews` in a `UIStackView` like so:

[image: layout]

Create an outlet for your `UIStackView` to your `UIViewController`. Call `addArrangedSubview` on your `UIStackView` in `viewDidLoad` to change the order. See snippet below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Switches order of the stackView
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(self.stackView.subviews[0])
    }
}
```

This should be the result:

[image]

The `addArrangedSubview` takes the given view and adds it to the end of the arrangedSubviews array. In our case we take the red view at index[0] and add it on the end (right) of the `UIStackView`.

Comment: what if i have 4-5 views inside stackview ?

Answer (score 13):

You can change the view `semantic` of UIStackView from `Unspecified` to `Force Right-to-Left` to swap the position of of nested view.

Comment: `teamOne.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft` doesn't seem to do anything for me, the result is the same

Comment: `hStack.semanticContentAttribute = checkBoxOnRight ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft` worked for in Xcode 12, Swift 5.2

Comment: Agreed with @ilikecode this did absolutely nothing for me xCode 13.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `addArragnedSubview` to reorder the views.
Only addArragnedSubview is needed because when adding the view to a new parent it is removed from the old parent.

```
    if self.viewsSwitched{
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(self.stackview.subviews[0])
        self.viewsSwitched = false
    }else{
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(self.stackview.subviews[1])
        self.viewsSwitched = true

    }
```

This code exchanges the two views inside the stackview by each call