# How to change the order of elements in stack view when changing axis in iOS?

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a horizontal uistackview with these elements:

> stack view (horizontal)  
>  element1     |     element 2

Then I change the axis programmatically.

```
buttonsStackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
```

Now the view is like this

> element1 
>  element2

I want to make it like this:

> element2 
>  element1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flipping the positions of items in a UIStackView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376482/flipping-the-positions-of-items-in-a-uistackview)

Answer (score 0):

put an axis checker, like this

```
if (stack view -> horizontal)
then element1 | element2
else
element2 | element1 (add elements again in the order you want)
```

hope this will help you